# First day of the week problem while using xts's period.apply()

Tags: r, xts, time-frequency, periodicity

I am trying to convert my daily series to weekly frequency by using xts package. However, I couldn't figure out how to dictate the first week of my series is Sunday. Documentation on function doesn't refer any arguments which can be used for this operation.

```
my_xts <- xts(mydf[, -1], order.by = mydf$Date, tzone = Sys.getenv("TZ"))
my_xts_weekly <- period.apply(my_xts, endpoints(my_xts, on = "weeks"), colSums)
nrow(my_xts_weekly)
```

Comment: no experience with `xts`package, but with `lubridate::wday` you can specify the week.start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xts split by week function specify first day of week as Sunday instead of default of Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603445/xts-split-by-week-function-specify-first-day-of-week-as-sunday-instead-of-defaul). You need the answer with the most upvotes, not the accepted one.